# How can I set Select by default in Spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I am to set select by default in spinner view. how can I do this

Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Spinner.setSelection(int position);
```

refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection%28int%29)